# Issue with IE Stripping off Anchor Tag

Tags: internet-explorer, url, url-rewriting, anchor

I am building a site that contains a menu with submenu items. Two of my submenu items are linked to anchor tags within one of my pages.  In FF and Chrome, they're working as expected, but in any version of IE the anchor tag is being stripped off the URL so my javascript is failing. I'm  using the anchor tag to determine which accordion list should be opened.

For instance, say I have http://www.sellingsickness.com/about/#organizers, IE renders this as http://www.sellingsickness.com/about/.

Link to the site is http://www.sellingsickness.com/ and the anchors are under ABOUT: Organizers and Steering Committee.

It's a wordpress site using the postname rewrite.

In .htaccess I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and my HTML:

jQuery to open the appropriate accordion based on anchor tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var currentHref = window.location.href;
 var anchorLink = currentHref.split("#");
 var accId = anchorLink[1];
  $("div#"+accId+"").parent().addClass('su-spoiler-open');
 document.getElementById(accId).style.display = "block"; 
 });
</script>
```